# Why am I Getting Different results from timestamp (datetime.datetime vs. pandas.Series datetime64)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have a pandas DataFrame including a column of timestamps (e.g. `1382452859`). Now I want to convert this column to ordinary date and time (e.g. `2013-10-22 18:10:59`).
I have tried two different approaches but I don't know why I get different answers:

```
# my DataFrame's head
df.head()
    Timestamp   Consumption
0   1382452859  12
1   1382452865  0
2   1382452871  12
3   1382452878  12
4   1382452884  12

#  getting the time of the first row using Pandas Series astype
df['Timestamp'].astype('datetime64[s]')[0]

output: Timestamp('2013-10-22 14:40:59') # which is 2013-10-22 14:40:59


# getting the time of the same row using datetime.datetime
dt.fromtimestamp(df.iloc[0]['Timestamp'])

output: datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 22, 18, 10, 59) # which is 2013-10-22 18:10:59
```

**1- I wanna know why these methods give me different results**

**2- I wanna know which method gives me the correct result**

**3- I wanna know how to get the same result using both methods**

Comment: I believe it is timezone related. `Timestamp('2013-10-22 14:40:59')` is using `UTC` timezone. But `datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 22, 18, 10, 59)` is using your locale timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fromtimestamp` gives you timestamp in your local time while `astype('datetime64[s]')[0]` on a dataframe gives time by default in UTC.

To get the time consistent in UTC, you should use `utcfromtimestamp` as mentioned below:

`print (dt.utcfromtimestamp(1382452859).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: _"fromtimestamp gives you timestamp"_ not sure what you meant here but I'm pretty sure you got something the wrong way around (`fromtimestamp` converts _from_ a timestamp, so it doesn't _give_ you a timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

I think best is use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) here with parameter `unit=s`:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')
print (df)
            Timestamp  Consumption
0 2013-10-22 14:40:59           12
1 2013-10-22 14:41:05            0
2 2013-10-22 14:41:11           12
3 2013-10-22 14:41:18           12
4 2013-10-22 14:41:24           12
```

[Difference between local and UTC datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921820) is reason for different datetime if test `dt.fromtimestamp`.